# Error loading a shared library when trying to run a Clojure project in NixOS

Tags: clojure, leiningen, nixos

I am trying to run a super simple Clojure project in NixOS 23.05.

The `project.clj` file contains:

```
(defproject fsm "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]
                 [com.phronemophobic/clj-graphviz "0.6.1"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot fsm.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}})
```

The file `src/fsm/core.clj` contains:

```
(ns fsm.core
  (:gen-class))

(require '[com.phronemophobic.clj-graphviz :refer [render-graph]])

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")

  (render-graph {:edges [["a" "b"]]})
  ;; writes to graph.png

  (render-graph {:edges [["a" "b"]]}
                {:filename "my-graph.png"}))
```

But when I enter `lein run`, I get the error message:

```
Execution error (UnsatisfiedLinkError) at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary/loadLibrary (NativeLibrary.java:323).
Unable to load library 'gvc':
libgvc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libgvc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Native library (linux-x86-64/libgvc.so) not found in resource path (...)
```

This works fine in other Linux distros (Pop OS!/Ubuntu), so I believe I am missing something with NixOS configuration. I am unfamiliar with this distribution.

Answer (score 1):

`libgvc.so` is a part of GraphViz. You need to install GraphViz to get access to that library. Do so however you please.

If you are not using Flakes for deploying/running your app, the easiest way to install GraphViz would be to use a Nix shell like so:

```
$ nix-shell -p graphviz
$ lein run
```

You can also add `graphviz` to your installed packages list the same way you installed `lein`.

Answer (score 0):

That `libgvc.so` is a shared object that *should* be installed on your system when you install Graphviz (see Installed Libraries [here](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/graphviz.html)). I say *should* because I'm not sure libgvc (Graphviz context library) is always included when you compile Graphviz.

Installing a library on NixOS means a different thing than installing a library on Ubuntu. This is because `apt` in Ubuntu (like most package managers in Linux distros) downloads precompiled binaries, while `nix` in NixOS checks if the required artifact exists in a [binary cache](https://zero-to-nix.com/concepts/caching), and if it doesn't exist, it compiles the source code and uploads the artifact to that cache.

As you can see from [this NixOS module in nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/23.11/pkgs/tools/graphics/graphviz/default.nix), Graphviz source code is first fetched from [this Gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz), then compiled using the tools declared in `nativeBuildInputs`. That NixOS module also takes care of ensuring that runtime dependencies are available on your system (see `buildInputs`).

If the `graphviz` package you find in nixpkgs **does include** libgvc, that package is probably fine and you should just double check your NixOS configuration. You should have something like this:

```
environment.systemPackages = [
  pkgs.graphviz
];
```

If the `graphviz` package you find in nixpkgs **does not include** libgvc, you can make a [derivation](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/inputs-design-pattern) that includes it.

You could also try compiling a small program that includes Graphviz, and use `ldd` to find all shared objects that the linker was not able to find.

```
ldd your-graphviz-program | grep 'not found'
```

See also how it's done [here](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Packaging/Binaries).

Bonus tip: when you want to bootstrap a quick Clojure project, use [dev-templates](https://github.com/the-nix-way/dev-templates).